# How to use bootstrap with semantic css using VS 2015 Asp.net Core

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

How can i use my own sass stylesheet using bootstrap. I know sass and in my projects i have a mainstylesheet.scss which i import all my other modules, grid, typhography, base and so on. I now am trying to understand how can i replicate this process but with using bootstrap. I want to still have semantic classes for my html adn css and not jstu attach css classes to whatever tag. i guess some refer to that as classitis. I have seen the @extend option but i don't get intellisense and i don't like that. I have imported bootstrap using bower and gotten a bower dependency and a folder in my lib folder under wwwroot. Do i need to change any of this. Before i had to have a "_" for everything that was going to import into my MainStyleSheet.Scss and then that compiled all my css.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is using Mixins. Bootstrap offers a few of them, but there doesn't exist a Mixin for every single class they have. Therefore you can only use a subset of Bootstrap's features, excluding everything that relies on JS to work on tags with specific bootstrap classes (which you don't want to use directly if I get you right).
But at least for the grid system and maybe some other core features there seem to be functions available which you can call with `@include`. For example, to make a class behave like the '.row' class with the bootstrap v4 beta you would to the following (after you imported bootstrap of course):

```
.my_own_row-like_class {
  @include make-row();
}
```

Note that the mixins do not necessarily have the same names as the classes and that Bootstrap 3 had even another naming convention for them.
I don't think there is a complete list of all available mixins, but they all seem to start with 'make-'. You can search for that in their github repository.

Answer (score -1):

The default template uses a set of  elements to render a top navbar and the main body of the page. If you’re using HTML5, you can replace the first  tag with a  tag to get the same effect, but with more precise semantics. Within this first  you can see there are several others. First, a  with a class of “container”, and then within that, two more  elements: “navbar-header” and “navbar-collapse”. The navbar-header div includes a button that will appear when the screen is below a certain minimum width, showing 3 horizontal lines (a so-called “hamburger icon”). The icon is rendered using pure HTML and CSS; no image is required. This is the code that displays the icon, with each of the  tags rendering one of the white bars:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

It also includes the application name, which appears in the top left. The main navigation menu is rendered by the  element within the second div, and includes links to Home, About, and Contact. Additional links for Register and Login are added by the _LoginPartial line on line 29. Below the navigation, the main body of each page is rendered in another , marked with the “container” and “body-content” classes. In the simple default _Layout file shown here, the contents of the page are rendered by the specific View associated with the page, and then a simple  is added to the end of the  element.

Comment: let me explain a little better and simpler. Before i was using something like this.    <button type="button" class="home-page__button"></button>  I want then to have my main style sheet like this.  .home-page__button { navbar-toggle;}.  How this works i am not sure as i see the extend method is possible in doing this. My question is how can i keep my semantic classes and just add my bootstrap css to my semantic css classes? Is there another method besides extend as that doesn't give me intellisense or maybe it does i just don't have something hooked up correctly.